# How to connect Insta360 Air Mini to my OWN app

Tags: android, virtual-reality, 360-panorama

i have Insta360 Air Mini camera the balck one with android port, I want to develop my own application in which I want to stream view from this camera, Has anyone tried this? please answer, Thanks
I have not found any developers guide on their site, however i have found for ricoh theta.

Comment: Any update so far?

Comment: No not yet, I am also requesting sdk from insta, but they want me to buy 20 pcs atleast. lets make our own :D

Comment: We could try to find 18 other buyers and do a collective request to Insta :)

Comment: Hahahaha, nice idea :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be outdated, but in case anyone still wonder on how to integrate insta360 devices to your on app, here is what to do:

1. Apply for the sdk through their official website [here](https://www.insta360.com/sdk/home) -requires model and serial number-
2. They will sent you an email to inform you if you request is accepted, if so they will provide the SDKs and [API documentation link](https://github.com/Insta360Develop)
3. Go through the docs and check the examples and that's it!

Comment: Thanks, at that time they want me to buy 20 pcs for the SDK.

Comment: anyway, the sdks are quite disappointing and outdated.